# React: Importing image from URL error handling

Tags: reactjs, image, import, error-handling

I am iterating over an API. That API contains links to pictures, that I like to visualize. I am doing it like that:

```
<img className={styles['picture']} src={props.flyerFront} alt="new"  />
```

The only problem is, that some of the links do not exist anymore (example link: "https://static.ra.co/images/events/flyer/2021/10/uk-1015-1467490-front.jpg?dateUpdated=1632838338373"). I would like to just put a predefined image instead and therefore I am asking myself, how do I catch the error?

error message from console:

[image]

EDIT: With the tips of the community I tried changes, which didn't help. For further clarification I put down the whole return statement below:

```
return (
        <div className={styles["container"]}>
            <div className={styles['pictureFrame']}>
              {typeof props.flyerFront !== 'undefined' > 0 ? 
              <img 
              className={styles['picture']} 
              src={props.flyerFront} 
              alt="new"  
              onError={event => {
                  event.target.src={cal};
                  event.onError = null;
              }}
              /> 
              : 
              <img className={styles['picture']} src={cal}  />}
            </div>
            <div className={styles['name']}>{props.title}</div>
            <div className={styles['date']}>| Date: {props.date}</div>
            <div className={styles['plus']}>
              <img src={plus} onClick={handleClick} />
            </div>
        </div>
      )
```

SOLUTION:

```
<img className={styles['picture']} src={props.flyerFront ? props.flyerFront : cal} alt="new"  />
```

Comment: you can do a condition based on `props.flyerFront`. If you provide part of the code it would be more clear in order to help you

Comment: Adjusted my post so you can see the whole return statement.

Comment: Glad too see the solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

try to import and call your image differently :

import foto from '/assets/images/foto.png';

Comment: Therefore I would need to download all pictures beforehand right? This is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `error` event, it's built-in event.

```
onError={event => {
    event.target.src = "https://default-image-link-goes-here"
    event.onerror = null
}}
```

Comment: I tried it like that, but it didn't change anything (see code above).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
src={props.flyerFront ? props.flyerFront : "default image here"}
```